# Difference Between Dates Program in Ruby not working

Tags: ruby

```
def getNumDaysInMonth(month, year)
  if (month ==1 || month ==3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 ||  month == 10 || month == 12   )
    return 31
  elsif (month == 2)
    if (isLeapYear?(year)== true)
        return 29 
    elsif (isLeapYear?(year)== false)
        return 28
    end 
  elsif (month == 4 || month == 6 ||  month == 9 || month ==11 )
    return 30
  end 
end

def isLeapYear?(year)
  if (year % 400 ==0)
    return true
  elsif (year% 100 != 0) and (year%4==0)
    return true
  else 
    return false 
  end 
end

def numDaysInYear(year)
  days = 365;
  
  if (isLeapYear?(year)== true)
    return days +=1
  else 
    return days 
  end 
end 

def differenceBetweenDates()
  puts "Enter in a starting date: "
  startDate = gets

  puts "Enter in an ending date: "
  endDate = gets 
  mdyArr = startDate.split("/", 3)
  mdyArr2 = endDate.split("/",3)

  startMonth = mdyArr[0].to_i 
  startDay = mdyArr[1].to_i
  startYear = mdyArr[2].to_i

  endMonth = mdyArr2[0].to_i
  endDay = mdyArr2[1].to_i
  endYear = mdyArr2[2].to_i

  differenceVal = 0

  if (startYear < endYear) 
    daysleftMonth = (getNumDaysInMonth(startMonth,startYear)) - startDay + 1
    differenceVal = daysleftMonth

    daysleftyear = 0

    counter = 1
    while counter <= 12 
      daysleftyear += (getNumDaysInMonth(counter,startYear))

      counter += 1 
    end 

    differenceVal += daysleftyear

    eachYear = 0

    counter = startYear + 1

    while counter < endYear            
      eachYear += (numDaysInYear(counter))

    end 

    differenceVal += eachYear

    daysleftyear = 0
    counter = 1

    while counter < endMonth 
      daysleftyear += (getNumDaysInMonth(counter, endYear))
    end 

    differenceVal += daysleftyear

    daysleftendMonth = 0 

    counter = 1
    while counter <= endDay
      daysleftendMonth += daysleftendMonth 
    end 

    differenceVal += daysleftendMonth
    puts differenceVal         
  end
end 

differenceBetweenDates()
```

Comment: What happens is the user gets promoted for the start year and end year and then nothing happens after that and the program just keeps going. It never exits so I'm not sure where I went wrong

Comment: You have a `while` loop whose exit condition depends on `counter` and `endMonth`. Neither of those variables is modified in the while loop, so it will run either zero times or forever.

Comment: your comment really helped me to look back at those while loops, my program is off by a couple days but it's definitely better than where I was. Thank you!!!!!

Comment: "not working" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Small suggestion: `startMonth, startDay, startYear = mdyArr.map(&:to_i)`

Comment: [Date#-](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-2D)

Answer (score 1):

First off, let's write Ruby like Ruby and cut your support methods down to a much more manageable bit of code. Remember that the value of the last expression in a method will be the method's return value. This includes conditional expressions like if/else.

```
def getNumDaysInMonth(month, year)
  raise ArgumentError.new("Month mus be between 1 and 12") if month < 1 || month > 12
 
  if [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12].include?(month)
    31
  elsif month == 2
    isLeapYear?(year) ? 29 : 28
  else
    30
  end 
end

def isLeapYear?(year)
  year % 400 == 0 || (year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0)
end

def numDaysInYear(year)
  isLeapYear?(year) ? 366 : 365
end
```

Where you run into problems is this loop:

```
 while counter < endYear            
    eachYear += numDaysInYear(counter)
  end
```

`counter` is never updated, so this loop never ends. You have a few more loops like this.

If you fix these, your program *will terminate*, though the output is incorrect.

You may wish to create a method `day_of_year` which determines how far a current day is into the year.

```
def day_of_year(month, day, year) 
  raise ArgumentError.new("Month must be between 1 and 12") if month < 1 || month > 12

  (1...month).map { |m| getNumDaysInMonth(m, year) }.sum + day
end
```

You can define a method in terms of that one to figure out how many days are left in he current year.

```
def days_left_in_year(month, day, year) 
  raise ArgumentError.new("Month must be between 1 and 12") if month < 1 || month > 12

  numDaysInYear(year) - day_of_year(month, day, year)
end
```

These are both nice, simple methods that are easy to understand. The larger problem can them be expressed in terms of them by adding the days left in the year of the start date to the day of year for the end date, plus the sum of the days in any years in between.

```
def date_diff(startMonth, startDay, startYear, endMonth, endDay, endYear)
  days_left_in_year(startMonth, startDay, startYear) +
  day_of_year(endMonth, endDay, endYear) +
  (startYear + 1 ... endYear).map { |y| numDaysInYear(y) }.sum
end
```

Comment: Or even `case month when 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12 then 31 when 2 then leap_year?(year) ? 29 : 28 else 31 end` (don't need `then` if in multiple lines)  — this is kind of a perfect scenario for `case` :)